# jQuery AJAX refreshes page and adds querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to do an AJAX post from my HTML page to a process.aspx page.  The ASPx page has an OnSubmit Web Method in code behind that will send an email once completed.

Right now, when I submit my form, the page refreshes and the 'data' from the ajax post is put in the querystring.  What am I doing wrong?

**CODE:**

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.aspx/OnSubmit',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("We returned: " + result.d);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Have you used fiddler or another web proxy to see exactly what is sent to the server on submit?

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors?  When you debug this, does this `submit` handler even run?  (Maybe it's not finding `#contactForm` when this executes?  What does the markup look like and when does this code execute in relation to loading that markup?)

Comment: It appears that I'm getting a parseerror somewhere in the AJAX call, but I'm not sure where...

SyntaxError: Syntax error

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do an ajax call by POST method you shoul'd use [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of [JQuery Submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/). Fist one do an ajax call and the second one *"Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element"*. What you're actually doing with your code is binding an ajax call to the event triggered by the submit of "#contactForm". JQuery Submit is intentioned (I Think) to do previos validations of the data submited, on the other hand JQuery Ajax actually do the call.
If you wanna submit the form using ajax, make a function that validates the data (not empty, etc) y get the values of the imputs, then send it using ajax (Bind this function to the submit function).
If you wanna send data by post using regular forms use the traditional  and (if you want) validate the data with JQuery Submit.
I suggest take a look into jquery docs (previous links).
Hope this helps my friend!